# How to fix Type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin

[Error message prompted by compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hq5v.png)Kotlin Type Parameters with Upper Bounds

I don't know what should I do.

---

In BaseActivity.kt

```
abstract class BaseActivity <T : IBasePresenter<*>> : IBaseView {}
```

---

In IBasePresenter.kt

```
interface IBasePresenter<T : IBaseView> {}
```

Comment: can you reformat the code?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
interface IBasePresenter<T: View> {
    fun attachView(view: T)
}
```

And Your `BaseActivity` should be like this:

```
abstract class BaseActivity <T : IBasePresenter<IBaseView>> : IBaseView { }
```

Use **`IBaseView`** instead of *****

Comment: I have re edit my code in my question ,please help me to check it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I fix it as follows.

```
abstract class BaseActivity <V : IBaseView, T : IBasePresenter<V>>  : IBaseView {}
```